# How to pass jquery varaible to php function

Tags: javascript, php

```
$('#to').focusout(function(){
 var dd = $("#from").val();            
 $("#con_from").val('<?php echo convert_to_db_format_dateonly('dd-mm-yy');   ?>');
});
```

I want to pass `dd` variable to my `convert_to_db_format_dateonly` function

Comment: Use AJAX instead, because you can't assign any value from client-side scripting language to server side scripting language

Comment: @amit.  Gud one,, that's the simple  explanation for this qus..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with ajax.

```
 function ajaxSubmit() {
 var data = 'dd=' +dd;

$.ajax({
    url: 'yourPHP.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
     //do something
      }
        else {

        //something else

        }
    },

       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

              }
          });
          return false;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can never pass your javascript value to php, php is the server side thing, in order to set a value to any variable from javascript, you can make an ajax call to set the value of your javascript variable to php.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Use a php page that gets this var by GET[]. You just grab the value by the $_GET and use the way you want.